# Create-project Laravel installation failed

Tags: php, laravel, installation

I have installed composer Composer version 2.0.1 2020-10-24 20:53:21
Now when I wanted to install Laravel in the folder by create-project. I get the following error:

```
|"Install of laravel/laravel failed

[RuntimeException]
Could not delete C:/Bootcamp Roots Files/Web/bootcamp/Projects/test1/.:

This can be due to an antivirus or the Windows Search Indexer locking the file while they are analyzed

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]"
```

How to solve this issue?
Please note that I checked my antivirus and Windows search index already.

Comment: What's the file in test1 folder that it's trying to delete? Try to delete it manually, or try running cmd with administrator privileges.

Comment: there is no file in test1 folder, its empty. I have tried with the administrator privilege and made no difference.